# Export iPad home screen bookmarks/Safari bookmarks to PC/Mac

Tags: ipad, bookmarks

How do you copy or export bookmarks and home screen web apps/bookmarks from iPad to PC/Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark syncing between Mobile Safari and Safari running on OS X or Windows is part of iCloud (included in OS X and available for Windows via [iCloud Control Panel for Windows v1.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US/)).