# Moving websites saved to the iPad Home screen to Safari bookmarks on Mac

Tags: ipad, icloud, safari, bookmarks

Context: My dad (not the best with tech) saved a lot of websites to the home screen of his iPad 2 (running iOS 9.3.5). He now has a MacBook Pro (new, running macOS 10.13 High Sierra), and I was tasked with trying to find a way to move those sites he saved back into bookmarks.

This answer didn't help at all, but I think my question was the same:

[Export iPad home screen bookmarks/Safari bookmarks to PC/Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57069/export-ipad-home-screen-bookmarks-safari-bookmarks-to-pc-mac)

Can I transfer these sites to bookmarks, or is all hope lost?

Comment: It will help to give better answer if you can edit the question and specify the version of iOS and macOS running on iPad and MacBook respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Tap on icon on Home screen of iPad to open in Safari.
2. Once the website is open in Safari, tap on the share icon and add the website as bookmark in Safari.
3. Repeat for all the website icons on Home screen one by one.
4. Go to Settings app → iCloud and turn on switch for Safari.
5. On your Mac, turn on iCloud sync for Safari.
6. The bookmarks should show up in Safari on Mac.

Comment: So just to be sure, there's no way to do them all at once? The real problem is that my dad saved over a hundred of these to his home screen.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to automate/speed up the task. But on the other hand, you’ll have to do it only once.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else comes up with anything but if not, I'll of course accept your answer.